# Alternative to ApplicationContext.getBean() in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot in my application and am currently using `applicationContext.getBean(beanName,beanClass)` to get my bean before performing operations on it. I saw in a couple of questions that it is discouraged to use `getBean()`. Since I am very new to Spring I don't know all the best practices and am conflicted. The solutions posed in the above linked question probably won't work in my use case. How should I approach this?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class APIHandler {
    @Value("${fromConfig}")
    String fromConfig;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Bot(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity post(@RequestBody HandlingClass requestBody) {
        SomeInterface someInterface = applicationContext.getBean(fromConfig, SomeInterface.class);
        someInterface.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I have an interface called `SomeInterface` defined like:

```
public interface SomeInterface {

    void doSomething();
}
```

And I have 2 classes which implements this interface called `UseClass1` and `UseClass2`. My config file stores a string with the bean name of a class which I need to know in run-time and call the appropriate implementation of the method.

Any directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Inject or Autowired the bean, you need use like @Autowired private SomeInterface someInterface;

Comment: I have thought of using @Autowired in the class where I am implementing the API but I am lost as to how I could call the correct implementation of `someInterface`

Comment: perhaps `someImpl`? :)

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth sorry didn't get that :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Spring 4.3 you can autowire all implementations into a Map consisting of pairs beanName <=> beanInstance:

```
public class APIHandler {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, SomeInterface> impls;

    public ResponseEntity post(@RequestBody HandlingClass requestBody) {
        String beanName = "..."; // resolve from your requestBody        
        SomeInterface someInterface = impls.get(beanName);
        someInterface.doSomething();
    }
}
```

assuming you have two implementations like following

```
// qualifier can be omitted, then it will be "UseClass1" by default
@Service("beanName1") 
public class UseClass1 implements SomeInterface { } 

// qualifier can be omitted, then it will be "UseClass2" by default
@Service("beanName2")
public class UseClass2 implements SomeInterface { }
```

Comment: This works for me perfectly! Just one question, Does this method doesn't go against the principles of DI?

Comment: What do you mean? `@Autowired` mechanism **is purposed** to maintain DI, hence it can't go against DI principles

Comment: how is the map populated?

Comment: it can even be caught by it's name like "useClass1" , "useClass2" since u don't define a name for it

Answer (score 2):

You can  define your spring bean component with

> `@Profile("dev")` , `@Profile("test")`

and `inject` as mention comment, then switch profile with

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test   jvm argument
```

Comment: Isn't profiles used as run profiles? By bean name wouldn't change from dev to test to production. Rather it would change for each call of the API class that I have shown.

Answer (score 2):

This is only code works for me to get beans dynamically from ApplicationContext

```js
@Service
public class AuthenticationService {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext сontext;

    public boolean authenticate(...) { 
        boolean useDb = ...;   //got from db
        IAuthentication auth = context.getBean(useDb ? DbAuthentication.class : LdapAuthentication.class);       
        return auth.authenticate(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Qualifier("student1")` is only possible if I know what the qualifier is beforehand but my use case is slightly more complex. I will get the bean name either from the config file or from the user dynamically. For eg. I might get the bean name from the POST request body.

Comment: I hope this helps you. May be you go with this approach

Comment: Is there any difference between what wrote and what you answered?
`applicationContext.getBean(fromConfig, SomeInterface.class);`
`context.getBean(useDb ? DbAuthentication.class : LdapAuthentication.class);`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should probably use a configuration class to produce your bean based on the `fromConfig` string value:

Your controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class APIHandler {

    @Autowired
    SomeInterface someInterface;

    @PostMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity post(@RequestBody HandlingClass requestBody) {
        someInterface.doSomething();
    }
}
```

The bean producer:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeInterfaceProducer {

    @Value("${fromConfig}")
    String fromConfig;

    @Bean
    public SomeInterface produce() {

        if (fromConfig.equals("aValueForUseClass1") {
            return new UseClass1();
        } else {
            return new UseClass2();
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

or if you have DI in UseClass1 and/or UseClass2:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeInterfaceProducer {

    @Value("${fromConfig}")
    String fromConfig;

    @Bean
    public SomeInterface produce(@Autowired YourComponent yourComponent) {
        SomeInterface someInterface;
        if (fromConfig.equals("aValueForUseClass1") {
            someInterface = new UseClass1();
            someInterface.setYourComponent(yourComponent);
            // or directly with the constructor if you have one with yourComponent as parameter.
        } else {
            someInterface = new UseClass2();
            someInterface.setYourComponent(yourComponent);
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that in the configuration file I need to hard code the `aValueForUseClass1`, so if I increase the number of classes implementing the interface, I would need to modify this configuration. Is this in line with the principles of DI?

Comment: Well, I understand. If you increase the number of classes, you have to use a `@Qualifier` for each of them, then You've got your `aValueForUseClassX`. 
And yes if you have a logical to get a specific implementation, you will have to modifiy the Bean Producer class of course and you should. If you want to deport the generation of bean to not use `applicationContext.getBean` it's a valid solution IMO, but that's one possible and non profile specific.

Comment: Will the above code work as is? Do you need to autowire the SomeInterfaceProducer  somewhere in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

The real question is not *how* to solve this, but *why* would you inject something different based on a configuration value?

If the answer is testing, then perhaps it's better to use `@Profile`s as @murat suggested.

Why are different implementations of an interface there on your classpath?

Can't you package your application in a way that only one is there for one use case? (see [ContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html))

Comment: No, the purpose is very much in production. There are multiple implementations if an interface because there is a chance of expanding on that interface. For eg. Each class might represent a table structure and I might have a generic API endpoint for calling the correct implementation based on the API data.

Comment: It's not too much information but based on that I think I would design this differently. But I would need much more information how to do so.